# Why no rep for participating on meta

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

Why don't we get reputation for votes on questions and answer here on meta?

I guess it would motivate people to participate in building the site.

Answer (score 7):

[This](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) blog post summarises the reputation for per-site Meta. The topic has also been brought up on MSO, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64268/189446) for example.

Basically, the Meta site doesn't serve as a place to gain rep.